# JS Date object undefined

Tags: javascript, object, date

I've written a function in JavaScript that returns, each time you invoke it, a new instance of this Object. Among its properties, this instance has a date property, which is being initialized when 'starting' this object (it's a **server** object):

```
instance.startedTime = new Date();
```

Later on, I have a function that returns this server instance' properties. When calling it, it returns 'undefined' for the instance.startedTime property.
Why is that, and how can I pass the date properly?

Comment: JavaScript is **client side** so you must be confusing something. Do you mean Java by any chance? Please give more details and retag the question as well.

Comment: I think you need to show the surrounding code, including the code that tries to return your property.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : why couldn't this be javascript? His naming of an object "server" doesn't doom it to be server side :)

Comment: @npup Because JavaScript, by its very definition, run client side and executed by the browser itself - the question says *it's a **server** object* - so something must be wrong here.

Comment: It is clearly javascript, and "server" is just a term here. Nothing in java returns an "undefined" value. +There is alot of javascript server side code these days.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save the time?

```
instance.startedTime = (new Date).getTime();
```

Comment: Is instance undefined, or instance.startedTime?